# How to enable chosen selectbox which is already disabled on button click in jquery?

Tags: jquery, jsp

how to disable chosen  select box  on page load in jsp  and then how to enable chosen select box on button click in jQuery ?
Below my code.

```
<select disabled="disabled"  class="chzn-select chosen-select-deselect chzn-select-width"  style="width: 100px"  id="workweekmonday" name="workweekmonday" >
<option value="0" selected="selected">Full Day</option>
<option value="4">Half Day</option>
<option value="8">Non-working Day</option>
 </select>
<div class="col-md-2  col-md-offset-3">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-theme02 btn-block" id="btnsaveworkweek">
<i class="fa fa-save"></i> Edit
</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").chosen();
    $("#workweekmonday").prop('disabled', 'disabled');  //On load disabled select

    $("#btnsaveworkweek").click(function(){
       $("#workweekmonday").prop('disabled', false);   //On button click enabled select
     });
});
```

**[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/66a15zoc/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#btnsaveworkweek").click(function(){
    $("#workweekmonday").removeProp('disabled');  
});
```

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/66a15zoc/